# Tortoise SVN 'check for modifications` command showing unmodified files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm having a problem with Tortoise SVN 'check for modifications' command, which for some reason has started to display a list of **all** files, including unmodified ones (those with Status 'normal').

How can I reconfigure Tortoise SVN to show only the modified files (those with Status 'modified')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source of the problem found:

Tortoise SVN 'check for modifications' command displays unmodified files which are locked.

This can be resolved by releasing the files with Tortoise SVN 'release lock' command.

I'm leaving this post here for other users to leverage from...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and the solution was to select the files, right-click, and "Remove from changelist"